# To which field is this quotient isomorphic $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle 2x-1, 5 \rangle}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to show the quotient $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle 2x-1, 5 \rangle}$ is a field and find to which field is this quotient isommorphic.

I think  this: $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle 2x-1, 5 \rangle}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle 2x-1 \rangle}$. The polynomial $2x-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ thus, the quotient $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle 2x-1 \rangle}$ must to be a field, but I don´t know to which is isomorphic.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the quotient ring?

Comment: $(2x-1)=(x-2^{-1})$ in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ and $R[x]/(x-a)\simeq R$ for every commutative ring $R$.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal ${\langle 2x-1, 5 \rangle}$ is the kernel of the epimorphism from $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\mathbb Z_5$ that sends $x$ to $3$ (and $1$ to $1$).

Comment: You probably mean "surjective morphism". Ring epimorphisms don't need to be surjective! See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81123