# Proof verification: $A$ is absolutely flat if and only if $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification, modules, flatness

This is a solution to Exercise 3.10 in Atiyah-MacDonald,

> (i) If $A$ is absolutely flat and $S$ is any multiplicatively closed
> subset of $A$, then $S^{-1}A$ is absolutely flat.
>
> (ii) $A$ is absolutely flat$\iff$$A_\mathfrak{m}$ is a field for each
> maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

(i) Suppose first that $A$ is absolutely flat. Note first that, for an $S^{-1}A$-module $M$, we have $$M \cong S^{-1}A \otimes_{S^{-1}A} M \cong (S^{-1}A \otimes_A S^{-1}A) \otimes_{S^{-1}A} M \cong S^{-1}A \otimes_A M \cong S^{-1}M.$$ In particular, if $$0 \longrightarrow M' \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow M'' \longrightarrow 0$$ is any short exact sequence of $S^{-1}A$-modules, then the exactness of the tensored sequence $$0 \longrightarrow M' \otimes_{S^{-1}A} N \longrightarrow M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} N \longrightarrow M'' \otimes_{S^{-1}A}N \longrightarrow 0,$$ where $N$ is any $S^{-1}A$-module, follows from the exactness of $$0 \longrightarrow S^{-1}M' \otimes_{S^{-1}A} S^{-1}N \longrightarrow S^{-1}M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} S^{-1}N \longrightarrow S^{-1}M'' \otimes_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}N \longrightarrow 0,$$ which is equivalent to the exactness of $$0 \longrightarrow S^{-1
}(M' \otimes_A N) \longrightarrow S^{-1}(M \otimes_A N) \longrightarrow S^{-1}(M'' \otimes_A N) \longrightarrow 0. $$ But this is obviously true, since $S^{-1}$ is an exact operation and $A$ is absolutely flat. Thus, $N$ is a flat $S^{-1}A$-module and hence $S^{-1}A$ is absolutely flat.

(ii) Suppose first that $A$ is absolutely flat, and let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $A$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the maximal ideal of the local ring $A_\mathfrak{m}$, and denote $k = A_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{p}$ as the residue field. Since $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is absolutely flat by (i), $k$ is flat as an $A_\mathfrak{m}$-module. In particular, if we tensor the exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow (x) \longrightarrow A_\mathfrak{m} \longrightarrow A_\mathfrak{m}/(x) \longrightarrow 0$$ by $k$ (as $A_\mathfrak{m}$-modules), where $x \in \mathfrak{p}$, we obtain the short exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow (x)/\mathfrak{p}(x) \longrightarrow k \longrightarrow k \longrightarrow 0.$$ Each element in the sequence below as a $k$-vector space; in particular, $k$ is finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space, so the surjectivity of the final map $k \to k$ also implies injectivity and the final map is thus an isomorphism. This implies $(x)/\mathfrak{p}(x) = 0$, so $(x) = \mathfrak{p}(x)$. By Nakayama's Lemma, $(x) = 0$. Since $x \in \mathfrak{p}$ was arbitrary, $\mathfrak{p} = 0$ and thus $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is a field.

Conversely, suppose $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is a field for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and let $M$ be any $A$-module. Then $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is an $A_\mathfrak{m}$-vector space for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, thus a free $A_\mathfrak{m}$-module, and hence a flat $A_\mathfrak{m}$-module. Thus, $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is a flat $A_\mathfrak{m}$-module for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$, which implies the flatness of $M$. Thus, $A$ is absolutely flat.

Is this proof correct? I ask because many parts of the proof involve computing tensor products and using the alternate algebraic structures of a particular mathematical object, which I'm not confident about and always queasy about exploiting.

Thank you for your help and advice in advance.

Comment: It is not in general true that $S^{-1}A \otimes_A S^{-1} A \cong S^{-1} A$, nor that $M \cong S^{-1} M$. For example if we take $S = A$ then $0 \in S$ so $S^{-1} M = 0$, but clearly not every module over an absolutely flat ring is trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure if the second part of your statement above disqualifies the proof; $M$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module, so if $S = A$, $M$ must be trivial (since $1x = x$ for all $x \in M$, but $1 = 0$). Are there concrete examples of $S^{-1}A \otimes_A S^{-1}A \not\cong S^{-1}A$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misread your claim! If $M$ is an $S^{-1}A$ module then my counterexample of course does not work because $0 \in S$ implies $S^{-1}A$ is trivial. I actually think the claim that $S^{-1}A \otimes_A S^{-1}A \cong S^{-1}A$ is true, though I am not sure how you would prove it without the conclusion that $M \cong S^{-1}M$. I know this at least follows from the case $M = A$ which itself follows from the universal property. Sorry for the mistake.

Everything else in your proof looks correct to me.

Comment: Please don't apologize, I'm happy that you took the time to read my proof! I verified my argument on the side, and I think it's true in general that $B \otimes_A B \cong B$ for any $A$-algebra $B$, and the isomorphism can be obtained using the universal property of $\otimes$.

Comment: This shouldn't be true in general for arbitrary $A$ and $B$. For example $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{C}^2$. However when $A \to B$ is a flat and an epimorphism (note that in CRing this is not equivalent to being surjective!), which is true when $B$ is a localization of $A$, you can tensor $0 \to \ker  \to A \to B \to 0$ by $B$. and get an isomorphism $B \cong B \otimes_A B$.

Comment: For a proof that the localization map is an epimorphism you can see this stack exchange post. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3351047/prove-localization-in-cring-is-epimorphism

Comment: I see; thank you very much for the correction and clarification.